# Testing for coefficients significance in Lasso logistic regression

Tags: logistic, statistical-significance, regression-coefficients, lasso, selectiveinference

[A similar question was asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108272/repeated-multiple-regression-for-lasso-significance-testing) with no answers]

I have fit a **logistic regression model with L1 regularization** (Lasso logistic regression) and I would like to test the fitted coefficients for significance and get their p-values. I know Wald's tests (for instance) are an option to test the significance of individual coefficients in full regression without regularization, but with Lasso I think further problems arise which do not allow to apply the usual Wald formulas. For instance, the variance estimates neded for the test do not follow the usual expressions. The original Lasso paper:

[Regression Shrinkage and Selection via the Lasso](http://statweb.stanford.edu/%7Etibs/lasso/lasso.pdf)

suggests a bootstrap-based procedure to estimate the coefficients variance, which (again, I think) may be needed for the tests (section 2.5, last paragraph of page 272 and beginning of 273):

> One approach is via the bootstrap: either $t$ can be fixed or we may optimize over $t$ for each bootstrap sample. Fixing $t$ is analogous to selecting the best subset (*of features*) and then using the least squares standard error for that subset

What I understand is: fit a Lasso regression repeatedly to the whole dataset until we find the optimal value for the regularization parameter (this is not part of the bootstrap), and then use only the features selected by the Lasso to fit OLS regressions to subsamples of the data and apply the usual formulas to compute the variances from each of those regressions. (And then what should I do with all those variances of each coefficient to get the final variance estimate of each coefficient?)

Furthermore, is it correct to use the usual significance tests (for instance Wald's test which makes use of the estimated betas and variances) with the Lasso estimates of the coefficients and the bootstrap-estimated variances? I am fairly sure it is not, but any help (use a different test, use a more straightforward approach, whaterever...) is more than welcome.

According to the answers [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153889/insignificant-coefficients-in-logistic-regression-after-lasso-variable-selection) I suspect inference and p-values just cannot be obtained. In my case, p-values are an external requirement (although the use of L1 regularization was my choice).

Thanks a lot

**EDIT**
What if I fit an OLS logistic regression using only the variables selected by a previous run of the Lasso logistic regression? Apparently (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153889/insignificant-coefficients-in-logistic-regression-after-lasso-variable-selection)),

> There's no need to run the model again after doing cross-validation (you just get the coefficients from the output of cv.glmnet), and in fact if you fit the new logistic regression model without penalisation then you're defeating the purpose of using lasso

But what if I do this with the sole purpose of being able to compute p-values while keeping the number of variables low? Is it a very dirty approach? :-)

Comment: To do inference for LASSO models you can also check out the CRAN package [hdi](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hdi/index.html) which provides inference for high-dimensional models, you might want to take a look at that...

Comment: The full methods are well described in this paper: http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ss/1449670857

Comment: And there's also package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/selectiveInference/index.html that may be useful to provide inference for the LASSO...

Answer (score 7):

The problem with using the usual significance tests is that they assume the null that is that there are random variables, with no relationship with the outcome variables. However what you have with lasso, is a bunch of random variables, from which you select the best ones with the lasso, also the betas are shrunk. So you cannot use it, the results will be biased.

As far as I know, the bootstrap is not used to get the variance estimation, but to get the probabilities of a variable is selected. And those are your p-values. Check Hassie's free book, Statistical Learning with Sparsity, chapter 6 is talking about the same thing. [Statistical Learning with Sparsity:
The Lasso and Generalizations](http://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/StatLearnSparsity/)

Also check this paper for some other ways to get p-values from lasso:
[High-Dimensional Inference: Confidence
Intervals, p-Values and R-Software hdi](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.4026.pdf).There are probably more.

Answer (score 5):

The issue with performing inference after model selection is that you are selecting the most predictive variables and then performing inference as if they were selected independently of the data. It is possible to show that refitting the regression model after doing model selection with the lasso (or any other model selection method!) may lead to $\sqrt{n}$-biased estimates (which is one reason why a simple Gaussian approximation will often fail for confidence intervals)

Fortunately, there has been much progress in recent years in developing inference methods that account for post-selection. Some relevant references for your case are:
[Exact post-selection inference, with application to the lasso](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1460381681)
and,
[Post-selection inference for l1-penalized likelihood models by Jonathan Taylor and Robert Tibshirani,
Stanford University](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.07358.pdf). The techniques discussed in these references are implemented in the R package selectiveInference- [selectiveInference: Tools for Post-Selection Inference | CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/selectiveInference/index.html)
. The selectiveInference package should produce the valid confidence intervals you need.

Comment: In the Machine Learning Specialization in Coursera by Univ. of Washington, the teachers of course 2 (Regression) devoted a whole week to Lasso regression. In one of the slides, the procedure I described (using Lasso to select features and then fitting a LS regression with only those variables) is denominated _debiasing_ and is considered correct and illustrated with graphs from a paper by Mario Figueiredo.

Check slide 105 here:

https://github.com/MaxPoon/coursera-Machine-Learning-specialization/blob/master/Machine-Learning-Regression/week5/week5_lassoregression-annotated.pdf

Comment: While they recommend debiasing the lasso, they do not discuss hypothesis testing at all. Also, the term de-biasing is misleading, because while refitting the model gets rid of the downward bias induced by the lasso, it doesn't help with the upward bias induced by the winner's curse. As far as I know, the only way to truly de-bias the regression coefficient estimates of the selected model is to compute the conditional maximum likelihood estimates. https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.09417