# Bootstrapping confidence interval for regression prediction

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, bootstrap

I want to use the regularized regression technique such as partial least squares (PLS), Lasso, and the elastic-net. However, as far as I know, there is no "standard" way of calculating the prediction interval for those methods. So can I use bootstrap (resample the training data, calculate the prediction) as a way to estimate the prediction interval? Will this method result in accurate coverage of the true mean response?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/241082/testing-for-coefficients-significance-in-lasso-logistic-regression

Comment: Are you asking about a confidence interval (on the coefficients), or prediction interval (on the output)?

Comment: @user20160 I am asking about the prediction interval