# test whether two samples are from the same high dimensional multinomial distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multinomial-distribution, small-sample, two-sample

I have two high dimensional vectors (~150 dims), assumed to be sampled from multinomial distributions. How can I test whether the two are from the same multinomial distribution or different ones? (Especially if the samples are small.)

Comment: Hello, I guess with this high dimensions, it is impossible to fit multinomial model and use a Wald/score/likelihood ratio test..
I think it is possible to use a LASSO regression and perform test with it, but I'm not familiar with that. This [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/241082/testing-for-coefficients-significance-in-lasso-logistic-regression) deals with that for logistic regression.
An easy option could be to go Bayesian, use a non flat prior for the probabilities of the models and do Bayesian model selection...